# Strange MSVC behaviour with std::experimental::is_detected

Tags: c++, c++14, sfinae, c++17

I implemented `std::experimental::is_detected` based [on this article on cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected) (Part of the code is below + working repro).

It works well on G++ and Clang++, but results in strange errornous behaviour with MSVC: `is_detected` seems to always be `bool_constant<true>`!

Here you can see the correct result using `gcc 5.x`:
[@ideone.com](http://ideone.com/VqYo3O)

But with MSVC 19 (shipped with VS2015) the tests always succeed:

```
Z:\>cl /EHsc test.cxx
....
Z:\>test
true, true
```

So, is this a known bug in the compiler? Is it related to Expression SFINAE not being implemented correctly? Is there any workaround I can use to make this work?

Thank you!

---

Here is part of the code that reproduces the error (I omitted the rest of the interface besides `is_detected` to increase legibility):

```
#include <iostream>

// void_t: void type alias
template< typename... >
using void_t = void;
//

namespace internal
{
    // Fallback case
    template<   typename D,
                typename Void,
                template< typename... > class Check,
                typename... Args 
            >
    struct detect_impl
    {
        using value_t = std::false_type;
        using type = D;
    };


    // Check succeeded
    template<   typename D,
                template< typename... > class Check,
                typename... Args 
            >
    struct detect_impl
        < D, void_t< Check<Args...> >, Check, Args... >
    {
        using value_t = std::true_type;
        using type = Check<Args...>;
    };
}

// Type representing a missing type.
struct nonesuch
{
    nonesuch() = delete;
    ~nonesuch() = delete;
    nonesuch(nonesuch const&) = delete;
    void operator=(nonesuch const&) = delete;
};


template<   template< typename... > class Check,
            typename... Args
        >
using is_detected = typename internal::detect_impl< nonesuch, void, Check, Args... >::value_t;



// Our test
template< typename T >
using is_addable_impl = decltype( std::declval<T>() + std::declval<T>() );

template< typename T >
using is_addable = is_detected<is_addable_impl, T>;


auto main(int argc, const char* arv[])
    -> int
{
    std::cout   <<  std::boolalpha
                <<  is_addable<int>::value  << ", "
                <<  is_addable<nonesuch>::value << std::endl;
}
```

---

**EDIT:** Strangely, directly using the void_t idiom works on MSVC:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct X {};

template< typename T, typename = void >
struct is_addable
    : std::false_type
{};

 template< typename T >
 struct is_addable <T, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<T>())>>
     : std::true_type
 {};

int main()
{
    std::cout   <<  std::boolalpha 
                << is_addable<int>::value   << ", "
                << is_addable<X>::value
                << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Z:\>cl /EHsc test.cxx
....
Z:\>test.exe
true, false
```

Comment: If you're trying this with the base VS2015, try at least update 1. Partial expression SFINAE support was added.

Comment: @chris Sadly, I am already using the latest CTP version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a workaround that appears to work with recent MSVC (tested with Visual C++ 19.00.23720.0):

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename...>
using void_t = void;

namespace internal
{
    template <typename V, typename D>
    struct detect_impl
    {
        using value_t = V;
        using type = D;
    };

    template <typename D, template <typename...> class Check, typename... Args>
    auto detect_check(char)
        -> detect_impl<std::false_type, D>;

    template <typename D, template <typename...> class Check, typename... Args>
    auto detect_check(int)
        -> decltype(void_t<Check<Args...>>(),
                    detect_impl<std::true_type, Check<Args...>>{});

    template <typename D, typename Void, template <typename...> class Check, typename... Args>
    struct detect : decltype(detect_check<D, Check, Args...>(0)) {};
}

struct nonesuch
{
    nonesuch() = delete;
    ~nonesuch() = delete;
    nonesuch(nonesuch const&) = delete;
    void operator=(nonesuch const&) = delete;
};

template <template< typename... > class Check, typename... Args>
using is_detected = typename internal::detect<nonesuch, void, Check, Args...>::value_t;
```

*(The dummy `void` parameter is unused now, it's there just to keep the rest of the implementation intact.)*

Answer (score 4):

You need a C++11 compiler to compile the above code, and MSVC 2015 is not a C++11 compiler.

The particular deficit in C++11 compliance you are running into is called "expression SFINAE" by microsoft.  Keep an eye out for it being fixed.

Basically, `decltype` cannot be used for SFINAE.  In laymans terms, SFINAE is the technique you are using for selecting overloads of template functions or classes.

There is usually no workaround.

Comment: I would say it is not a standard compliant compiler.  It does support most C++11/14 features,

Comment: (Look at my edit) Then why is it the case that directly applying the void_t idiom is working, but the indirect way using detect_impl is not?

Comment: @Naschkatze Maybe.  The behavior of their compiler under `decltype` tends to be flaky and fragile (rather than "clearly not working").  Sometimes I get it to work, but barring access to their source, I am not able to predict it.

Comment: @NathanOliver You are more charitable than I am.  That is permitted.

Comment: To be fair, it does not pretend to be a C++11 compiler: `__cplusplus == 199711L` ;)