# SFINAE: decltype on operator[]

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sfinae

Based on answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36079170/how-to-check-if-a-member-name-variable-or-function-exists-in-a-class-with-or) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35661129/strange-msvc-behaviour-with-stdexperimentalis-detected) I am trying to use the following

```
template <typename T>
using operator_square_brackets = decltype(&T::operator[]);
```

It fails on visual studio with

```
error C2760: syntax error: expected ')' not ']'
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Which version, out of interest?

Comment: 2017 64 bit ...

Comment: Does using declval and then manually indexing work? `template <typename T, typename I> using operator_square_brackets = decltype(std::declval<T>()[std::declval<I>()]);`

Comment: Can you show slightly more context? How your *metatype* is used?

Comment: The method of @AlexanderHuszagh is the only correct one.  Otherwise this fails for, e.g., `T = int[]`.

Comment: Your type doesn't support overloads, and `T` would probably define const and non const  one together.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to detect whether a type has a certain function or overloaded operator you have to call that function or operator.  This is important because you might have several overloads of a function or operator and overload resolution always depends on the caller.

Here is a small example, based on [CppCon 2014: Walter E. Brown "Modern Template Metaprogramming: A Compendium, Part II"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a0FliKwcwXE&t=29m7s) on how to detect `operator[]` in a type.

I have no idea why VC is giving you such a weird error which looks more like a parsing error.  I would have expected something like »reference to overloaded function could not be resolved; did you mean to call it?«.

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

// in C++17 std::void_t
template < typename... >
using void_t = void;


template < typename T, typename Index >
using subscript_t = decltype(std::declval<T>()[std::declval<Index>()]);

template < typename, typename Index = size_t, typename = void_t<> >
struct has_subscript : std::false_type {};

template < typename T, typename Index >
struct has_subscript< T, Index, void_t< subscript_t<T,Index> > > : std::true_type {};


struct A
{
  void operator[](size_t) {}
};

struct B {};

int main ()
{
  static_assert(has_subscript< std::vector<int> >::value    == true , "!");
  static_assert(has_subscript< std::vector<double> >::value == true , "!");
  static_assert(has_subscript< A >::value                   == true , "!");
  static_assert(has_subscript< A, std::string >::value      == false, "!");
  static_assert(has_subscript< B >::value                   == false, "!");
  static_assert(has_subscript< double[5] >::value           == true , "!");
  static_assert(has_subscript< double* >::value             == true , "!");
  static_assert(has_subscript< double >::value              == false, "!");
}
```

Comment: [is_detected](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/1169/sfinae-substitution-failure-is-not-an-error/18585/is-detected#t=201707210748041399684) may interest you to generalize the concept.

Comment: `std::map<std::string, int>` would be a good example for an `Index` which is not `size_t`.

Comment: If you don't use the error message parameter of `static_assert`, you can just omit it.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Not prior to c++17.

Comment: I'm trying to use this, while it checks for the operator overload, it does not specialize for subscript type, will return true every time.

Comment: @joaocandre Yes, you might be interested in this question then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45249985/how-to-require-an-exact-function-signature-in-the-detection-idiom

Comment: @HenriMenke I'm tied to c++11 atm, so that solution won't do. Still, was just finding it curious why your example explicit defines  `typename Index` and seems to not use it. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong,